# Why does my button not click?

Tags: android

I have tried looking for other answers but my efforts have been futile, I seem to have done everything right and have even seen a couple tutorials on how to go about it. For some reason, when I run the emulator, my button does not work at all. There is no response. I at first thought it might be a wrong password but then the error message also doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final EditText inEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inEmail);
        final EditText inPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inPassword);
        Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        final TextView tCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tCaption);
        TextView tHyperLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tHyperlink);
        Log.d("SOS", "onCreate: Here");

        tHyperLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Register.class);
                startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.d("SOS", "Reached");
                if(inEmail.getText().toString().equals("m") && inPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals("o")){
                    Intent Main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(Main);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                    msg.setMessage("Login Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the corresponding xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="com.bludevs.twotor.LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inEmail"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inPassword"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inEmail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/twotor_logo"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tCaption"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Not a member yet?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bLogin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.781"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.231" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tHyperlink"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text= "@string/Register"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tCaption"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bLogin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.778" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Share your xml file Yash

Comment: Your code seems bug free, Did you registered your Activities in Manifest class?

Comment: No I did not. How do I go about doing that. Also, why would that cause the button to not click?

Comment: I am posting it here.

Comment: paste your activity's full code.

Comment: That is my full code? The problem appears to be that the button does not register any clicks. I tried printing to the console when the onClick Method was triggered and nothing printed.

Comment: try logging inside onClick() function to check if it is coming inside that function or not.

Comment: I changed my code. I logged both outside the click and inside the click.

Comment: I have the same code as yours and mine is responding accordingly. I would suggest you to debug the application; put a break point on the "if" statement where it's checking the values of the string and run the app in debug mode. Once it hits the break point, click on "Evaluate Expression" or hit Alt + F8 (should open a small window). Put in your if statement in there and see if it returns true or false. (I often use this to solve errors)

Comment: Updated my answer below. Should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> -UI related event handlers are better inside OnCreate.
> -If you need otherwise, you should take views and context into  
> consideration rather than using a void function
> -Following should help.
> ```

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        final EditText inEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inEmail);
        final EditText inPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inPassword);
        Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        final TextView tCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tCaption);
        TextView tHyperLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tHyperlink);

        tHyperLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Register.class);
                startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(inEmail.getText().equals("m") && inPassword.getText().equals("o")){
                    Intent i_Main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i_Main);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                    msg.setMessage("Login Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are we using "Intent Main"? It should be a keyword. Please use Intent i_Main. Answer has been updated with the changes.

Answer (score 4):

Replace your button click code with this:

```
  if (inEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals("m") && inPassword.getText().toString().trim()`enter code here`.equals("o")) {
            Intent Main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(Main);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder msg = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
            msg.setMessage("Login Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
        }
```

You have to convert your EditText value to String by using toString() method.
and also you can use trim() method to remove extra space.

Comment: I just debugged your application and found the same answer. I think this should be the accept answer. You didn't convert your the value in your edittext to a string variable and this is why you were unable to compare the value to "m".

Comment: But that still doesn't seem to work, I did try that. That also implies that it should enter the 'else' block, which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not register your app in manifest class. 
So go to your manifest class. and add these lines accordingly.

```
      <activity
        android:name="YourActivityName"
        />
```

Also change `inEmail.getText()` to `inEmail.getText().toString()`

Comment: My activities appear to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.bludevs.twotor">

        <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".Register">
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```